# How to spawn a new Process to invoke a .net core console application?

Tags: c#

I have a .net core console application named `ShowDate`.

```
using System;

namespace ShowDate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
        }
    }
}
```

After building I get `ShowDate.dll` rather than `ShowDate.exe`. I have tested it via terminal

```
dotnet ShowDate.dll
```

and it produces date time without problem.

Now I create a second .net core console application as follows.

```
namespace InvokingShowDate
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "dotnet";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "ShowDate.dll";
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

            p.Start();

            p.WaitForExit();

        }
    }
}
```

and it fails to run with the following error.

[image]

## Question

What is wrong? How to solve it?

## Edit:

Of course I have copied the `ShowDate.dll` and pasted it into the output folder of the second project.

Comment: I believe that you need to use the dotnet publish to actually produce an executable. From the [docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-build?tabs=netcore2x): "If the project has third-party dependencies, such as libraries from NuGet, they're resolved from the NuGet cache and aren't available with the project's built output. [...] the product of dotnet build isn't ready to be transferred to another machine to run. This is in contrast to the behavior of the .NET Framework, [...] To have a similar experience with .NET Core, you need to use the dotnet publish command."

Comment: @mikez: Either published output or normal built output works if both `ShowDate.dll` and `ShowDate.runtimeconfig` are available for the second console app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently to solve it, I have to copy both `ShowDate.dll` and `ShowDate.runtimeconfig.json` and paste them to the output directory of the second project.

Comment: There is a github issue describing this [here](https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/7692).

Comment: I assumed you had dropped the extension. You are proposing that there are two files associated with .NET core, an app.runtimeconfig and a app.runtimeconfig.json, which produce similar errors in a similar situation? In all likelihood you have windows set to hide known file extensions.

Comment: @mikez: You are correct. The file ends with `.json`. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your second console app need to define entry point :

```
"buildOptions": {
    ...
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
```

Comment: which .Net core version you using

Comment: hmm, I am checking around. I faced similar issue in context of asp.net core and adding that to json file helped. but with 2017 i agree there is no .json file.